# Learning Play with an eye towards Play 2.0

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I've recently started teaching myself the Play! Framework.  (I like it a lot.)  I know Play 2.0 will be out soon, so what should I focus on learning?  What will be the same/different in Play 2.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will be differences, but the best advice is to get used to the template engine that is part of the Scala module. I would expect there to be some kind of tutorial for transitioning between the two, but the advice that has been given to others is that using the scala version of Play1.x will be relatively seamless transition to play2.x.

Answer (score 2):

First of all Play 1.0 will supported in the future too. So it's not wrong to learn it. If you interested to learn scala the answer from [Codemwnci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696204/learning-play-with-an-eye-towards-play-2-0/8696366#8696366) is good. Otherwise I think you can start with Ebean, which is the default database layer in 2.0 and Japid for the templates.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  What is Codemwmci?

Comment: @Joe Codemwnci is the author of the other answer.